# EMFCompare results as XML

Tags: compare, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

Is there a pre-built method in [EMFCompare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) that outputs the differences between two models in XML?

If not, where is the best place to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the diff as XML format using the "export DiffModel" button in the top right hand corner of [EMFCompare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/)'s view.